# TypeError: row indices must be integers, not str In python insert Query

Tags: python, insert, typeerror

This Is  My code to Insert Data In One Table From Select data two Another Tables.
Please Help to identify, what is Error in my Insert Query

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd


cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                      "Server=LAPTOP-6HKL6V6K;"
                      "Database=DemoTest;"
                      "Trusted_Connection=yes;")

Anxiety=0
Hostility=0
Depression=0
Confidence=0
Compassion=0
Happiness=0

cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor2 = cnxn.cursor()
cursor3 = cnxn.cursor()
data2=('select top(1) ArticleURL,Name,Date,CreationTs,Category,Year,Location,Organization,Person from ClassificationAnalysis ')
cursor.execute(data2)
for row1 in cursor.fetchall():

     data=cursor2.execute("Select * From SentimentAnalysis where ArticleURL='%s'"%row1.ArticleURL)

 #data=cursor2.execute('select SentimentAnalysis.ArticleURL,ClassificationAnalysis.Year,SentimentAnalysis.Entity,ClassificationAnalysis.Name,ClassificationAnalysis.Date,ClassificationAnalysis.CreationTs,ClassificationAnalysis.Category,ClassificationAnalysis.Location,ClassificationAnalysis.Organization,ClassificationAnalysis.Person ,SentimentAnalysis.Score,SentimentAnalysis.Aspect,SentimentAnalysis.Emotion from ClassificationAnalysis join SentimentAnalysis on ClassificationAnalysis.ArticleURL=SentimentAnalysis.ArticleURL where ClassificationAnalysis.Date=SentimentAnalysis.Date')
for  row in cursor2.fetchall():
     #  print(data)
       if(row.Emotion=='Anxiety'):
         Anxiety=row.Score
        # print(Anxiety)
         if(row.Emotion=='Hostility'):
           Hostility=row.Score
          # print(Hostility)
           if(row.Emotion=='Depression'):
              Depression=row.Score
           #   print(Depression)
              if(row.Emotion=='Confidence'):
                 Confidence=row.Score
              #   print(Confidence)
                 if(row.Emotion=='Compassion'):
                    Compassion=row.Score
                   # print(Compassion)
                    if(row.Emotion=='Happiness'):
                      Happiness=row.Score
                 #     print(Happiness)
data1=cursor3.execute("INSERT INTO SentimentClassification (ArticleURL, Name, CreationTs, Date, Year, Location, Person, Category, Organization, Aspect, Entity, Score, Anxiety, Hostility, Depression, Confidence, Compassion,Happiness) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"  ,row1['ArticleURL'], row1['Name'], row1['CreationTs'], row1['Date'], row1['Year'], row1['Location'], row1['Person'], row1['Category'], row1['Organization'], row['Aspect'], row['Entity'], row['Score'], Anxiety, Hostility, Depression, Confidence, Compassion,Happiness)
print(data1)
```

**Error In Insert Query:**

> TypeError: row indices must be integers, not str In python insert
>   Query

Answer (score 0):

Replace the second to the last line to

```
data1 = cursor3.execute("INSERT INTO SentimentClassification (ArticleURL, Name, CreationTs, Date, Year, Location, Person, Category, Organization, Aspect, Entity, Score, Anxiety, Hostility, Depression, Confidence, Compassion,Happiness) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"  ,row1.ArticleURL, row1.Name, row1.CreationTs, row1.Date, row1.Year, row1.Location, row1.Person, row1.Category, row1.Organization, row.Aspect, row.Entity, row.Score, Anxiety, Hostility, Depression, Confidence, Compassion,Happiness)
```

Comment: It would help if you fix the formatting of your code, and I think there are logical errors in your code, but I'm submitting the above as an answer to your current question

Comment: Can you Help me to Solve my Logical Error

Comment: Sure, but you have to update your question with what you are actually trying to do in that code.